# How to set 2 different color for different texy in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

How to set 2 different colors in FPDF??

I have tried the code below

```
$pdf=new FPDF();                     
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
$pdf-> SetMargins(25, 50);
$pdf->SetTextColor(91,137,42); 
$pdf->SetFont('times','',10);
$pdf -> Text (60,  37,  'Title' ); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('times','',15);
$pdf -> Text (60,  37,  'Invoice' );
```

But for all tests it is displaying a single color.

Any solution for this?

Comment: well, you don't create anything in the color you first set. Why would you expect to get stuff in two colors then?

Comment: that is just exp, i set 0 0 0, but actually heding i need to show in red color.other thing i need tp show in green color.

Comment: After setting the first color _you do not output anything_. If you do not output anything, then you will not see anything. You only output anything after setting the color the second time. That is why you see everything in one color.

Comment: BTW: you should use the fpdf successor `tfpdf` instead. Same code base, same feature set, but unicode enabled.

Comment: I did check, your code works as expected. I posted my check in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I made a minimal working example from your code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');    
$pdf=new FPDF(); 
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5'); 
$pdf->SetMargins(25, 50); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(91,137,42); 
$pdf->SetFont('times','',10); 
$pdf->Text (60,  27,  'Title' ); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(99,0,0); 
$pdf->SetFont('times','',15); 
$pdf->Text (60,  57,  'Invoice' );    
$pdf->Output('test.pdf');
```

When holding the generated document open (`okular test.pdf`), changing the color values and re-running the code I can see the document getting updated and the colors change. The code works as expected.

---

Considering the first version of your question and your comments I could imagine your issue is with getting a text color in the header of a page? This also works as expected if you follow the documentation:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class myPDF extends FPDF {
  function Header() {
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    $this->setTextColor(0, 120, 120);
    $this->Cell(80);
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Page title',1,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
  }
}

$pdf=new myPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
$pdf->SetMargins(25, 50);
$pdf->SetTextColor(91,137,42);
$pdf->SetFont('times','',10);
$pdf->Text (60,  27,  'Heading' );
$pdf->SetTextColor(99,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('times','',15);
$pdf->Text (60,  57,  'Invoice' );
$pdf->Output('test.pdf');
```

Note that in this case the text color has to be set *in the Header() function*, not later, when you create a page which features the header...

This is the resulting document, you can clearly see the colors: 
[image]